# MVC Architecture issue

Tags: java, model-view-controller, servlets

I have been reading a lot on MVC but really don't know if i am clear on the concepts of MVC or not
recently developed an application what i did is
1)on jsp load called a function
2)using AJAX called a servlet and servlet is there performing all the logic
3)servlet called a java bean and a java class to perform some logic and return result
4)based on the result returned form the class i am displaying an image say if result is 1 then image A ,if 0 then Image b
5)on servlets POST method i am using out.println()-->to write the complete output
6)the function on jsp after returning the call will set the innetHTML of required div by the output generated by the servlet

now say the output servlet is producing is the table

---

instance name|instance state

---

now if i want at some time to change the display for this table to say

---

instance state|instance name

---

to do the above mentioned change i have to recompile my servlet and redeploy the war

is it really a MVC?
and someone suggested me to use JSON store object of a bean containing data as JSON and then return the JSON object to the jsp
and at jsp using this object contruct the table!

any pointers on this will be of great help!!

Answer (score 0):

Whether you have to redeploy usually depends on your development environment. If your using an IDE that builds automatically as you make changes, and the server is run from the IDE you are using, you may not need to rebuild the war. You can always try to view the source code to see if you need to redeploy. Back end code usually has to be redeployed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the ajax reponse obtained.

You can hide or show the images that you tend to.

How about getting the image link instead of out.print printing the bytes[] if i am not wrong.

When you want to redirect to another page, how about redirecting it from the servlet itself using response redirect.

Answer (score 0):

**Lets have a quick look at what is MVC?**

`MVC(Mode-view-controller )` as the name suggests is software architecture pattern , which encourages application to `have its Model Classes (i.e domain models / DTOs)  views (i.e can be JSP, JSON etc) and controller (i.e Servlet) to be as modularized as possible so that it encourages re-usability, loose-coupling between the different layers and Seperation of Concerns`.

So the key idea behind this to `encourage Seperation of Concerns` .
`Say i want to change the view from JSP to freemarker view , if MVC is tighly followed , i should be able to accomplish the change with minimum to no impact to Controller layer (i.e Servlets)`

Well you see this can only be achieved if had clear layer separation in my webapp.
`If i had just scattered all the functions without regard to MVC like having views generated from the Servlet, or making service level calls like accessing the DB directly from the Controller etc  is bad because any change in the view or the Database layer will cause massive changes at the Servlet .`

So to answer your question , `your servlet should not directly produce the HTML output`.
`Store all the objects` that would want to generate view `in Request Attribute` and `access it in JSP`
And to recompile Sevlet doesnt mean you dont follow MVC , just that by following MVC your changes are minimal and are grouped at a single place.

For now drop JSON concept , make it plain and simple
Go through this tutorial , which fairly explain you how to achieve a neat MVC

[Jsp MVC tutorial.](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/jsp/jsp_mvc_tutorial.htm)

Once you grasp , you can always add more complex things like JSON, AJAX , Asynchronous Request etc

Comment: thnks for all the help provided :)